# Android - Blocks in XML

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio, autolayout

I am currently working on an Android project, Android Studio. I wonder if it's possible to make blocks (8 in total) Android Studio. These blocks will be in the part below the menu bar. I joined my `content_main.xml` you file, so you can help me.

**I would view 8 blocks (4 blocks on one line, and 4 more on the one below).These blocks will be used to display weather data (graphics, text).**

I makes you available to the project at this link:
[Project on Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/vks3oozhr0r8bu1/AADpQwbSAiIc8Ua8LRVCDWlja?dl=0)

Thanks you in advance for your help, McNavy.

Comment: share code on DropBox ? seriously ?

Comment: and BTW, what do you means by blocks ?

Comment: Probably.  A picture of what you want would make it easier.  Also, this has nothing to do with Android Studio-  that's just a tool used to make writing code easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to use [MaterialLeanBack](https://github.com/florent37/MaterialLeanBack) library.

You will get a sample example in the code for understanding.

### Usage

In your layout

```
<com.github.florent37.materialleanback.MaterialLeanBack
        android:id="@+id/materialLeanBack"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        app:mlb_background="@color/background"
        app:mlb_lineSpacing="30dp"

        app:mlb_paddingBottom="30dp"
        app:mlb_paddingLeft="30dp"
        app:mlb_paddingRight="30dp"
        app:mlb_paddingTop="40dp"

        app:mlb_titleColor="@android:color/white" />
```

### Requires

```
compile 'com.github.florent37:materialleanback:1.0.0@aar'

compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.1'
compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
```

[image: Sample layout]