# Keep one and only one Child View on Screen In Recycle-view Horizontal scroll?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, horizontal-scrolling

I am developing an app in which there are many products that are stored in sqlite Database.

I have made a Recycler view and Cardview that scroll horizontally. But the scroll it self is too smooth and the child do not stop in center.

**Only one child should be visible (like in tab viewpager).**

Should I use viewpager to do this but will have to create so many fragment.

Comment: it is better to use view pager for this purpose. and for this you dont need to create so many fragment. one one fragment will be used to represent your data. but it refresh its view when you will change the page in viewpager

Comment: Use [this library, check answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35519128/2826147)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, Can you redirect to some example of sort ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.retail.R;
import com.retail.beacons.beaconModel.OfferBeaconData;
import com.retail.manager.UserProfileManager;
import com.retail.ui.view.RobotoLightTextVew;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by mahendra.chhimwal on 1/14/2016.
 */
public class BeaconOffersPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    private Activity mContext;
    private List<OfferBeaconData.OfferItem> mOfferItems;

    public BeaconOffersPagerAdapter(Activity context, List<OfferBeaconData.OfferItem> offerItems) {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.mOfferItems = offerItems;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mOfferItems == null ? 0 : mOfferItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == object;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(final ViewGroup container, final int position) {
        View view;
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_beac_off_pager_item, container, false);
        ImageView offerItemImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.iv_offer_image);
        RobotoLightTextVew tvWelcomeMsg = (RobotoLightTextVew) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_welcome_msg);
        RobotoLightTextVew upperTitle = (RobotoLightTextVew) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_upper_title);
        RobotoLightTextVew bottomTitle = (RobotoLightTextVew) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_bottom_title);
        RobotoLightTextVew discountText = (RobotoLightTextVew) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_offer_discount);

        //Updating views
        Picasso.with(mContext).load(mOfferItems.get(position).getOfferProduct().getImageUri()).into(offerItemImage);
        upperTitle.setText(mOfferItems.get(position).getOfferTitle());
        String userName = UserProfileManager.getInstance().getName();
        if (userName != null && userName.length() > 0) {
            int toIndex = userName.indexOf(" ");
            if (toIndex != -1) {
                userName = userName.substring(0, toIndex);
            }
            tvWelcomeMsg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            tvWelcomeMsg.setText(mContext.getString(R.string.welcome_greeting, userName));
        }
        bottomTitle.setText(mOfferItems.get(position).getOfferSecondTitle());
        discountText.setText("" + mOfferItems.get(position).getOfferProduct().getMaxDiscount() + "% off");  

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((View) object);
    }
}
```

You can use Simple PagerAdapter for that perpose. Inflate your views just like RecyclerViewAdapter. Above is sample example I am using in my code. **No need to use Fragment either.**

Comment: Thanks, works exactly as wanted with minor adjustments

Comment: You are welcome.If it worked for you, then please marked it as answer for others who face similar problem, they will get helped from too.

Answer (score 0):

it is for compatible only Android Lollipop. Android Lollipop two new widgets to make your life easier, RecyclerView and CardView.you have to create simple tab viewer

Comment: Though you do not have reuptation to comments on question, it is not a good way to represent. Better wait until you have proper reputation to comment